# How to use same class library on WCF and Silverlight application

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, class-library

Hi I would like to use the same class library from my Silverlight application and WCF based service. I created a Silverlight C# class library and found the WCF service does not allow adding reference to Silverlight Project types. So

- What should i do to make this work?
- Can Silverlight invoke methods on Silverlight Class library if it communicates with WCF service?
- Is silverlight always this hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portable Class Library

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try making 2 class libraries, one for Silverlight and one for WCF. Both use the same C# source code files. In the second project, you can add the files as link (In Visual Studio in solution explorer: add existing item, and then in the drop-down Add button, choose "Add as link".

That's how we solved it for shared code. You have to limit yourself to library calls that exist in both worlds though.

Comment: What difference does it make If i copy the files to both the project(silverlight class library, C# class library) than adding a link. by the way you should have looked at my previous question too here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477345/c-sharp-class-library-silverlight-class-library-asmx-web-services-wth btw i think WCF Ria Class library was designed to solve this problem.

Comment: Also the `List<Customers>` returned from the service when converted to SL based class library object does not expose Methods , i can see only the properties Why is this so ?

Answer (score 1):

Now it is easy :D - just use the `.shared` trick. It allows you to share the same code between server and client. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707371(v=vs.91).aspx

PS.: You can even add conditional directives on your .shared classes, like this:

```
#if SILVERLIGHT
        MessageBox.Show("yay, I will run only on silverlight");
#endif
```